# Automatically Sign In Sharepoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sharepoint, single-sign-on

I want to sign in to a SharePoint portal through calling a web page. Forms based authentication is enabled on SharePoint. 
The scenario is as follows:

1. Calling  */_forms/default.aspx?username=userX*. which is the default page for forms authentication in sharepoint.
2. The page create and set authentication ticket for userX without asking his password.
3. The page redirected to some default page.

I have tried to manipulated  */_forms/default.aspx* to create ticket using FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken, 
but no result.
I'd greatly appreciated if some one helps me.

Comment: After you set `FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken` you need to send this token to `SPFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken`. Once this is done, SharePoint will be able to authorize user.

Comment: check `EstablishSessionWithToken` method in below link:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1757882.aspx?creating+security+token+updates+all+user+in+membership+table+